# How to read XML generated by SVN in Powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell, svn

Am getting the following xml output through svn diff command.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<diff>
<paths>
<path
   props="none"
   kind="file"
   item="modified">SDLC\Reports\Phase1 Analysis\report_phase1_code.xls</path>
</paths>
</diff>
```

I only need the complete path of the file i.e. "SDLC\Reports\Phase1 Analysis\report_phase1_code.xls" through powershell. However, because of the other attributes like props, kind, etc. present in the output, I am not getting the file path value.

Powershell code written is as follows:

```
[xml]$XmlDoc = Get-Content -Path output.xml

foreach( $user in $XmlDoc."diff".paths) 
{ 
    Write-Host $user.path
}
```

Any help on this topic would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Should just have to do this:

```
foreach( $user in $XmlDoc."diff".paths) 
{ 
    Write-Host $user.path.'#text'
}
```